# Get output and input into daemon processes

Tags: io, daemon, ipc

**Background**

When a SIGHUP is sent to a running nginx master process to reconfigure, if there're password encrypted certificate key, nginx(specifically the openssl library) will ask for input, as in the log:

```
Enter PEM pass phrase:
```

since there are no input handle, this immediately fails and causing failed reload.

**Question**

Is there any convenient ways to know when nginx is asking for a password and input into it?

**Thoughts**

- `ssl_password_file` directive is not an option since it leaves traces on the disk.
- Wrapping nginx in another parent process and run it in foreground is better, but I fear this might add some instability to nginx.
- So I think it should be best to solve with some Linux mechanism. Possibly named pipes? But I think named pipes needs the participation of Nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a directive meant for that :
You can configure NGINX to use a list of passwords separated by lines stored in a file by using **ssl_password_file**.
.

```
http { 
  server { server_name <fqdn|ip>;
  ssl_certificate_key <pem_key>; 
  ssl_password_file <path_to_passphrase>
      }
```

Then reload the configuration :

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

Note that your passphrase file should be readable ony by root user.
Also there is a security breach if an attacker get access to your passphrase.

Comment: `ssl_password_file` was not an option before since our boss doesn't like to write password on disk. But I have figured out a work around, I made a named pipe file so I can use it to pass password to this directive. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Hashicorp Vault (https://www.nginx.com/blog/protecting-ssl-private-keys-nginx-hashicorp-vault/) or an alternative.